# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:Unknown error occurred while processing request on server.status code returned from server:503

Tags: sql, reporting-services, powerbi

I am getting the below error when I try to run a SSRS report.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 503

I am connecting SSRS 2017 with SAP HANA and am getting this error.

Any idea of why am I getting this error and how this can be fixed?

[image: Error Snip]

Comment: Seems to be an issue with available memory.  [Check this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8920fdc4-b6c7-476a-a418-c44603c2e2d3/report-services-integrated-mode-error-503-after-100-seconds?forum=sqlreportingservices) for some possible solutions.  Make sure the queries aren't performing slowly and if they seem to be okay, the link provides some options that can be adjusted to solve the problem.

Comment: This probably is not a memory issue coz at times the report runs and most of the times it throws this error. Just as a note, my Site_Desc parameter has almost 5K values. Do you think that may be an issue?

Comment: That's very possible.  All I know is that when you throw `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: 503` into a google search, most of the results return some solution involving adjustments to `timeout` values.  If there's any way to have that parameter depend on another parameter which would limit the number of values loaded in that dropdown, that would probably be a good idea -- even if it isn't the source of the error.

Comment: [More info on the error received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb397479(v=vs.140)).  Seems to be a server side error as I look around in the Google results a bit more.  Can't really say what that could mean?  Seems that some people have gotten it when multiple users are running the report at the same time.  Maybe adding a `(NOLOCK)` to the slower queries could alleviate the issue. Not ideal, but an option.